# How to use Gateway REST endpoint from Restcomm?

Tags: rest, sip, voip, restcomm

I have registered gateway, but I cant accept call from it. How to use Gateway REST endpoint? Is any docs od examples?

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by registered gateway ? On Documentaiton, please See http://documentation.telestax.com/connect/api/gateway-api.html#gateways

Comment: I have SIP peer in Asterisk. Then in restcomm I create Gateway to this peer (by host, login and password). Now I want to call from Asterisk to Restcomm (and to route this incoming call to some client e.g. Alice

Comment: Can you help me?